# Light bulb spins in recessed but won't unscrew

Tags: lighting

I had a bulb that spins in recessed light can, it won't unscrew, how do I get it out?

Answer (score 4):

Probably the glass bulb has separated from the base.

1. Wear eye protection and heavy gloves.
2. Turn off power to the socket.
3. Pull the glass portion of the bulb out forcibly, breaking it if necessary.  By spinning it around several times, you might be able to keep the glass intact and simply break the wires to the base.
4. Unscrew the base from the socket by whatever means is convenient:  pliers, cardboard tube (like from a toilet paper or paper towel roll, with one end squished to fit), potato ([video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y0QjfD0LVH8), [text](http://www.wikihow.com/Remove-a-Broken-Light-Bulb-with-a-Potato)), etc.

Comment: +1 And I would open the breaker, not just turn off the switch. Sometimes fixtures are miswired and the neutral rather than the hot is switched.